Failed to validate the selected authentication type. Azure openai studio error
Getting this error in Azure openai studio add your data section.
Failed to validate the selected authentication type.
How to resolve?
I have attached the roles from this link, but still its not working. I have even provided the contributor access to managed identity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/use-your-data-securely#role-assignments

enter image description here

You should specify in your question as much information as possible. There is no indication of what or where you data source is, or what you have added the Contributor role to. Reply once added.

Check if you disabled public network access on your storage account.

@ArchitectJamie, The data source is AI search, both openAi and AI search have public access enabled and even the storage account is public.
I have tried the other data source Azure Blob Storage and Upload files, but still the error is same.

What about api, does it work?
Also, have you created custom domain in your azure open ai resource. You can check that from the Networking blade. You need to if have not already.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
